# when use CHtmlPurifier and Chtml::encode()

Tags: yii

i am new to yii-framework. so when to use `CHtmlPurifier` or `Chtml::encode()`.if i am using any of them how can i customize this condition  ?? 
Plz help me

Comment: this question is too vague, what do you want to ask exactly?

Answer (score 0):

`ChtmlPurifer` is expensive, I would tend to use this in a beforeSave() method when the input may have HTML formatting involved from a user. You can use it to specify what tags are acceptable.

`encode()` I would use if you are not using purify on any user specified inputs. For instance, if someone had had a title i would use encode() to make sure it's safe to use.

Comment: Jonnny how can over ride this function

Comment: @RahulG What function do you want to override? And in what situation